# Incomplete Google Drive REST API results for Team Drive files

Tags: google-drive-api, google-api-client, google-python-api

**Problem**

During the first phase of my Team Drive backup system, I first need to scan files in the given Team Drive in order to determine which files to copy for backup.

> I (think?) have full permissions over the files & folders of the Team Drive, due to the credentials I use (set to `Owner` in the cloud console).

Nevertheless, my problem is that when I query the REST API for a file listing of a given Team Drive, the results do not comply with the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/python/latest/drive_v3.files.html#get). The returned file objects only contain 5 fields that are:

- `kind`, `name`, `id`, `mimeType`, `teamDriveId`

According to the documentation provided, I should receive a handful more of fields.

Below is the code I use to query the API and the output.

**Simplified source**

```
credentials = get_credentials() # retrieves and processes app credentials
drive = get_drive_api(credentials) # get the drive API v3 using httplib2 and discovery
query = drive.files().list(
    pageSize = 10,
    corpora = 'teamDrive',
    supportsTeamDriveItems = True,
    includeTeamDrives = True,
    teamDriveId = "..."
)
results = query.execute() # contact the REST API
files = results.get('files', [])
for file in files:
    print(file)
```

For the given Team Drive, output is

```
{
  'kind': 'drive#file',
  'id': '...',
  'name': 'filename',
  'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.document',
  'teamDriveId': '...'
}
```

Which clearly isn't the expected output according to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/python/latest/drive_v3.files.html#get).

**Any insights on the reason I do not get the complete expected data ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[With Google Drive API v3 full resources are no longer returned by default. Use the `fields` query parameter to request specific fields to be returned. If left unspecified only a subset of commonly used fields are returned.](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/migration)

To fetch all available fields of the resource you can set `fields` to `*`.

For example:

```
query = drive.files().list(
    pageSize = 10,
    corpora = 'teamDrive',
    supportsTeamDriveItems = True,
    includeTeamDrives = True,
    teamDriveId = "...",
    fields="*"  # or maybe "files(id,name,capabilities/canShare),nextPageToken"
)
```