# Google Team Drive file list not showing all files

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

When using the [v3 of Google Drive API for listing files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) I get either no results or an incomplete list of results when querying a team drive content.

I've double-checked:

- the team drive permissions for the service user I am using
- I am setting the `setSupportsTeamDrives` and `setIncludeTeamDriveItems` parameters
- I am setting the `setPageSize` explicitly and am using the paging mechanism with `setPageToken` and `getNextPageToken`

Yet, the call to `GoogleApiClient.drive.files.list....execute()` succeeds, but returns too little results (when compared to eyeballing).

What could be wrong?

(Note the other question [Incomplete Google Drive REST API results for Team Drive files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46180485/incomplete-google-drive-rest-api-results-for-team-drive-files) is not a duplicate as the other one is about incomplete "columns", not "rows")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be avoided if you explicitly set the `corpora`, e.g.

```
     .setCorpora("teamDrive")
     .setTeamDriveId("0000REDACTED")
```

Otherwise the list of results seems to be subjectively decided by Google with no clear criteria applied.
As of moment of writing this (Nov 2018) [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) doesn't seem to mention the default value for the `corpora` when not specified.